# If statement using NumericUpDown

Tags: vb.net

I want to make an `If` statement using NumericUpDown so that every time the value goes less than the threshold, the NumericUpDown ForeColor turns to red, otherwise black.

For example: I set the threshold to 3. My problem is when the NumericUpDown reaches from 10-30, the ForeColor turns to red. 10-30 is greater than 3, so why does that happen?

```
Private Sub Txt_item_quantity_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txt_item_quantity.ValueChanged
    If numericupdown1.value.toString <= lbl_item_threshold.Text Then
        numericupdown1.ForeColor = Color.Red
        'ToolTip1.Active = 1
    Else
        numericupdown1.ForeColor = Color.Black
        'ToolTip1.Active = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a string compare in your IF.  String compare compares character by character so 10, if you look at the first character 1 is less than 3.  Convert to numbers to compare values.

Answer (score 0):

Do the comparison like this where integer values are compared instead of string values.

```
If numericupdown1.value <= CInt(lbl_item_threshold.Text) Then
```

Comment: Note that this will throw an exception if `lbl_item_threshold.Text` can't be converted to an integer.

Comment: @Timato1 - Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

@RobertBaron has provided the correct answer. I am posting this to elaborate on the "why".
Strings sort by alphabetical order and Integers sort by numeric order. To demonstrate

```
Private Sub TestSort()
    Dim StringArray() As String = {"1", "2", "30", "10", "4"}
    Dim IntegerArray() As Integer = {1, 2, 30, 10, 4}
    Array.Sort(StringArray)
    Array.Sort(IntegerArray)
    For Each s In StringArray
        Debug.Print(s)
    Next
    'Result
    '1
    '10
    '2
    '30
    '4
    For Each i In IntegerArray
        Debug.Print(i.ToString)
    Next
    'Result
    '1
    '2
    '4
    '10
    '30
End Sub
```

As you can see, when dealing with strings, 4 is greater than 30 but when using Integers 4 is less than 30 - the expected result.